# redis behind ha proxy - multiple connection retries and connection closed

Tags: redis, haproxy, ubuntu-16.04

Ha proxy configuration for redis shows the following:

```
frontend redis
  bind *:6379 name port6379
  mode tcp
  timeout client 15s

    #define hosts
    acl redis_3 hdr(host) -i im.test.com

    #figure out which one to use
    use_backend test_redis if redis_3

backend test_redis
  mode tcp
  timeout connect  4s
  timeout server   30s
  #balance leastconn
  option tcplog
  option tcp-check
  tcp-check send PING\r\n
  tcp-check expect string +PONG
  #tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
  #tcp-check expect string +OK
  server node1_redis 10.146.99.164:6379 check inter 1s
```

HA proxylogs show multiple Connects to redir. On the redir server I see "Connection reset by peer"

In the browser I get a 'reinitialized session'.

But with redis-cli -h  ping I get a correct PONG response. Directing the browser directly to the redis server on port 6379 give the following after a short while:

```
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
-ERR unknown command 'Host:'
-ERR unknown command 'User-Agent:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept-Language:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept-Encoding:'
-ERR unknown command 'Cookie:'
-ERR unknown command 'Connection:'
-ERR unknown command 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:'
```

HAproxy stats show backend is up.

Can anyone help me with this? Why do I get an error when connecting through HA proxy?

Comment: when using redis-cli set hello world on the redis server I get a connection when directly connecting with curl to the redis server. But when I use the HAproxy to connect it gives an error (52) Empty reply from server

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The host name for some reason was not read in the acl. Instantly when I changed it to a default backend it worked.

Maybe someone can tell me why the hostname in this example did not work?

But for me it works now.

Jan